# "Field is required" error shows up on every required field once I make a selection on a select

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2

I'm currently making a custom UI-component for the `adminhtml` form which extends the default UI-select element. But the issue is that when I make a selection on this new UI-select all fields have their values cleared and if they are required the error appears.

I've been debugging for a while and have reached the conclusion that this issue appears down the line when the code gets to this.value(data) and also throws an exception.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

The element which is clicked in this case is the same element from the normal UI-select.

This is the component's XML through which it's added to the form.
And yes the `options` shouldn't be there but I couldn't figure out where to put it otherwise to make it work.

```xml
<field name="programs" class="Mirasvit\Affiliate\Component\Filters\Type\MultiplePrograms">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Programs</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Mirasvit_Affiliate/form/elements/multiple-programs</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Mirasvit_Affiliate/js/component/multiple-programs</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Mirasvit\Affiliate\Ui\Account\Source\Program</item>

                    <item name="tableOptions" xsi:type="object">Mirasvit\Affiliate\Ui\Program\Source\ProgramsWithTiers</item>
                    <item name="tableValues" xsi:type="object">Mirasvit\Affiliate\Ui\Program\Source\AccountPrograms</item>
                    <item name="tableFields" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="name" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="tier" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Tier</item>
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="fixed" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Fixed tier</item>
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

This is the component's js file

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select',
    'uiRegistry',
], function (_, $, Abstract, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({

        defaults: {
            optionsCache: [],
            options: [],
            listVisible: false,
            tableOptions: [],
            tableValues: [],
            tableFields: {},
            currentSelected: [],
        },

        toggleOptionSelected: function (data) {
            if (this.lastSelectable && data.hasOwnProperty(this.separator)) {
                return this;
            }

            this.options(this.options.without(data));

            /**
             * THIS IS WHERE THE COMPONENT BREAKS
             */
            this.value(data);

            this.listVisible(false);

            return this;
        },

        cleanHoveredElement: function () {
            if (this.hoveredElement) {
                $(this.hoveredElement)
                    .children(this.actionTargetSelector)
                    .removeClass(this.hoverClass);

                this.hoveredElement = null;
            }

            return this;
        },
    });
});
```

And this is the component's php file

```php
class MultiplePrograms extends Select
{

    public function prepare() {
        $config = $this->getData('config');

        /** @var ArrayHelper $helper */
        $helper = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ArrayHelper::class);

        if (isset($config['tableOptions']) && $config['tableOptions'] instanceof ArrayInterface) {
            $config['tableOptions'] = $config['tableOptions']->toOptionArray();
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Missing tableOptions tag for multiple-options field');
        }

        if (isset($config['tableFields'])) {
            $config['tableFields'] = $helper->nameToColumn($config['tableFields']);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Missing tableValues tag for multiple-options field');
        }

        if (isset($config['tableValues']) && $config['tableValues'] instanceof ArrayInterface) {
            $config['tableValues'] = $config['tableValues']->toOptionArray();
        }

        if (isset($config['options']) && $config['options'] instanceof ArrayInterface) {
            $config['options'] = $config['options']->toOptionArray();
        }

        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);

        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to store information in the value of this component so that it can be passed to the controller later

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this was happening.
The reason it was throwing that error is because `this.value()` contained all the form data and thus by setting `this.value({anything})` to anything, would clear all of the fields stored and trigger the errors and the observers.